# Serverless scheduled, detect cron

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'd like to run a function via both HTTP and cron, but not seeing any documentation that let's me determine if it was an http request or cron request (explicitly):

```
    events:
      - http:
          path: /foo
          method: ANY
          cors:
            origin: '*'
      - schedule: rate(5 minute)
```

Is there a property in `event` or `context` that would allow me to detect what triggered the function?

Comment: From what I'm finding it looks like `!event.httpMethod` is probably the most explicit I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always pass an input to your schedule event and use that to determine that's a schedule event

```
events:
  - http:
      path: /foo
      method: ANY
      cors:
        origin: '*'
  - schedule:
      rate: rate(5 minute)
      input:
          isSchedule: true
```

There's more examples here: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/schedule/

EDIT:

Forgot about this

```
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "53dc4d37-cffa-4f76-80c9-8b7d4a4d2eaa",
    "detail-type": "Scheduled Event",
    "source": "aws.events",
    "account": "123456789012",
    "time": "2015-10-08T16:53:06Z",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "resources": [
        "arn:aws:events:us-east-1:123456789012:rule/my-scheduled-rule"
    ],
    "detail": {}
}
```

you can also check `detail-type` field
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html